# In VSCode, sometimes closing an unsaved untitled tab doesn't close it

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode, I sometimes create a new editor with Cmd-N to paste some temporary data into, which I don't save. When I'm done, I generally close the tab and VSCode asks me if I want to save it and I say "don't save".

But sometimes, when I try to close the tab, VSCode doesn't ask me if I want to save it, and while the editor does disappear, VSCode remembers that I have it open.

Notably, the file will continue to show up in the "Other files" section of the Search tab when I search for text contained in it.

How do I consistently get an editor of a new unsaved file to actually close?